# Validate each value of an ArrayField of emails in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, validation, django-models

I am using PostgreSQL with Django and am trying to use `ArrayField(models.EmailField(max_length=200))`. But I am ending up with an `500 error code(TypeError)` when giving invalid email address.

How can I validate each email in the ArrayField. I have tried writing validate method in both serializer and models. But nothing helped. What is the right way to validate ArrayFields? I am using Django 2.1 and Python 3.6

The traceback of the error is given below...please have a look

**models.py**

billing_emails = ArrayField(models.EmailField(max_length=200))

company = models.OneToOneField(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

## Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-Amy45Zrz/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-Amy45Zrz/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 156, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-Amy45Zrz/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 154, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-Amy45Zrz/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 106, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-Amy45Zrz/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 72, in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-Amy45Zrz/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djangorestframework_camel_case/render.py", line 8, in render
    return super(CamelCaseJSONRenderer, self).render(camelize(data), *args,
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-Amy45Zrz/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djangorestframework_camel_case/util.py", line 17, in camelize
    new_dict[new_key] = camelize(value)
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-Amy45Zrz/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djangorestframework_camel_case/util.py", line 16, in camelize
    new_key = re.sub(r"[a-z]_[a-z]", underscoreToCamel, key)
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-Amy45Zrz/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 191, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Forms, use [Form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/) or [Serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/), you can use the `clean_<attribute_name>` method to validate the data. For example:

```
from django.core.validators import email_re
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):  # serializers.ModelSerializer

    def clean_billing_emails(self): 
         data = self.cleaned_data['billing_emails']
         for email in data:
             if not email_re.match(email):
                 raise ValidationError('Invalid email {}'.format(email)  # or raise serializers.ValidationError
         return data
```

Also you can use  [model's clean method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean).

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    ...
    def clean(self):
         try:
              for email in self.billing_emails:
                  if not email_re.match(email):
                       raise ValidationError('Invalid email {}'.format(email) 
         except (TypeError, Exception)  as e:
              # log error
              # handle error

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        return super(YourModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Can you share your stacktrace in your question please?

Comment: How are you storing the data? It seems you are not getting string or byte object. You can't run validation on these without these data types.

Comment: Also added a minor change in models as well